# Literature recommendation - non-stationary heat transfer in porous solids

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, conductivity, chemical-engineering

I am trying to calculate a non-stationary heat transfer to a porous spheres by conduction.

These spheres are placed in a thin metal tubes with a known heat capacity. Hot/cold air (or similar gaseous mixture) flows around the tubes to either cool or heat them.

I am particularly interested in calculating the time it takes for a defined temperature to appear in the center of these sphere. The material of these spheres has homogenous composition.

Do you have any tips on the literature that would describe this problem in a simplified way or better yet, provided concrete problems solutions?

Comment: What about a combination of «chemical engineering» with «heat transfer» and «sphere»? In one of the search engines I use, Faith Morrison, Michigan Tech appears again and again with lecture notes like [this pdf](https://pages.mtu.edu/~fmorriso/cm3215/Lectures/CM3215_Lecture10HeatConductSphere_Fall2015.pdf); or [engineeringnotes.com](https://www.engineeringenotes.com/thermal-engineering/heat-conduction/conduction-of-heat-through-a-sphere-thermal-engineering/30154). I didn't assume this could be done with Excel, but this may depend on the level of detail you aim for.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thank you. Honestly, I went through library and looked to a well-known books of Bejan - Convection Heat Transfer and Thermodynamics by McGraw-Hill, which did not turn out to be an ideal sources. The presentation is especially great! I did not expect analytical solution, so this is more than fine. Actually, I need an accurate estimation, as my goal is to fasten the heat transfer by getting a dependance on the particle size, heat transfer properties including the metal tube material and the flowing medium (temperature, velocity).

Comment: With your addition of «dependance on the particle size, heat transfer properties including the metal tube material and the flowing medium (temperature, velocity)», you tap more into chemical/civil engineering (heat exchangers, flow reactors with catalyst beads, etc.) since each of them (assuming a fixed incoming flux of heat) may affect at least the temperature (incl. locally along the direction of flux). So you need to parameterize the approach and to define if the process is going to be run under isothermic/stationary or adiabatic conditions (are tubes thermally insulated, or not).

Comment: Yes, my specification was rather poor in the post. The first calculation will be done for constant conditions (size, packing density, physical parameters of the materials  - density, conductivities, heat flux (air highly concentrated with CO$_2$ at 393K) and its volumetric flow / velocity). After I get results, I would like to make sort what you have described - a parameters optimization (maintaining values of available metals / particles (shapes, porosities)) and find optimal scenario for which the heating / cooling takes the least amount of time while maintaining the process economy.